# Set Environment Variables for Django on Dreamhost and Passenger WSGI

Tags: django, linux, passenger, dreamhost

I'm trying to set an environment variable for Django that will not be in the source, in this case an email password. This is the example I'm trying to emulate:

```
server: /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-superlists-staging.ottg.eu.service

[Service]
User=elspeth
Environment=EMAIL_PASSWORD=yoursekritpasswordhere
WorkingDirectory=/home/elspeth/sites/superlists-staging.ottg.eu/source
```

The example uses nginx and gunicorn, but I'm attempting a setup with Dreamhost, Linux and Passenger wsgi.

Here is my file structure:

```
.
|-- \ ~
|-- __pycache__
|-- database
|-- etc
|-- passenger_wsgi.log
|-- passenger_wsgi.py
|-- passenger_wsgi.pyc
|-- public
|-- source
|-- static
|-- superlists
|-- testGoat
|-- tmp
`-- virtualenv
```

superlists is where the project is located. So, how should I go about setting the Environment Variables in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution while reading Two Scoops of Django. Apache doesn't allow for setting Environment Variables. Instead, I added a secrets.json file to my /etc folder and used a method within settings to read the secret data out of the JSON file. Here's what the method looks like:

```
import os

# 2 Scoops 5.4.1, Env Varible Alternative
import json 
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# JSON-based secrets module (see 2 Scoops, 5.4.1)
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../etc/secrets.json')) as f:
    secrets = json.loads(f.read())

def get_secret(setting, secrets=secrets):
    '''Get the secret variable or return explicit exception.'''
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = 'Set the {0} environment variable'.format(setting)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_secret('SECRET_KEY')
EMAIL_HOST = get_secret('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = get_secret('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = get_secret('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = get_secret('EMAIL_PORT')
```

And the JSON file looks like so:

```
{
    "FILENAME": "secrets.json",
    "SECRET_KEY": "shhhh...it's a secret",
    "DATABASES_HOST": "127.0.01",
    "PORT": "5432",
    "EMAIL_HOST": "smtp.email.com",
    "EMAIL_HOST_USER": "name@email.com",
    "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD": "123456",
    "EMAIL_PORT": "000",
    "EMAIL_USE_TLS": "True"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are meant to be environment so I assume that you start your server with a script. Assuming it in bash you can create a file fo example

**env_variables.sh**

```
export SECRET_KEY=...
export DB_NAME=...
...
```

or do the same in python file with `os.environ`.

Then in the settings of the app load the environment variables with `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` for example.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As far as I know Dreamhost doesn't allow me to start the server with any particular scripts. I found another method that works using a JSON file.